# .next() in php shows random blank values

Tags: php, html-table, iteration

I have this big form that I pass trough post method to a PHP page.. in which the `$POST` variable has 2 arrays, that might be a little different from each other depending on how the user fills the form, so for that I iterate from the `$POST` variable to see if its an array and if it is then a make a table from the value, thing is sometimes the `.next` value doesn't seems to read the value in one array but in the other one it does read it perfectly.

Here's my for each code:

```
foreach($_POST as $var){
if(is_array($var)){
    foreach($var as $x => $value){
        if($value != ''){
        switch ($x) {
case "nombreOtrosMeds":

$otrosMedicos.='
     <table class="tg">
        <tr>    
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Nombre: </strong> '.$value.'</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Dirección: </strong>'.next($var).'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Teléfono: </strong>'.next($var).'</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Fax: </strong>'.next($var).'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    ';
    break;
case "tipoCirugia":
$algunaCirugia.='
     <table class="tg">
        <tr>    
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Tipo de cirugía: </strong> '.$value.'</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Hospital: </strong>'.next($var).'</td>
            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Fecha de cirugía: </strong>'.next($var).'</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    ';
    break;
}
        }

    }

}
}
```

as you can see it is the same in all of the cases but the result im getting is:

```
Tipo de cirugía: cirugia1 Hospital: Fecha de cirugía: 
Tipo de cirugía: Cirugia2 Hospital: Hospital2 Fecha de cirugía: 2015-10-15
```

and the arrays are like this:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [nombreOtrosMeds] => 
        [dirOtrosMeds] => 
        [telOtrosMeds] => 
        [faxOtrosMeds] => 
        [tipoCirugia] => cirugia1
        [hospital] => hospital1
        [fechaCirugia] => 2015-10-07
        [tipoNoCirugia] => hospitalizacion1
        [Nohospital] => hospital hospitalizacion1
        [fechaNoCirugia] => 2015-10-04
        [tomaMedNombre] => 
        [tomaMedDosis] => 
        [tipoDroga] => droga1
        [cantidadDroga] => cantidad droga 1
        [tiempoDroga] => timepo droga 1
        [tipoDieta] => 
        [cantidadPesodDieta] => 
        [fechaDieta] => 
    )

[cirugias] => Sí
[2] => Array
    (
        [tipoCirugia] => Cirugia2
        [hospital] => Hospital2
        [fechaCirugia] => 2015-10-15
        [tipoNoCirugia] => Hospitalizacion2
        [Nohospital] => Hospital Hospitalizacion2
        [fechaNoCirugia] => 2015-10-13
        [tipoDroga] => droga 2
        [cantidadDroga] => cantidad droga 2
        [tiempoDroga] => tempo droga 2
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE (**after** the comments):

You can use the following code. Iterate through all your post data and check if the first element is `tipoCirugia` so echo appropriately. If it's some other column then this means that user has post different data so echo something different.

```
$data = $_POST;
$i = 0;
foreach($data as $var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
        $element = 0;
        foreach($var as $key => $value) {
            if ($key == 'tipoCirugia' && $element == 0) {
                $otrosMedicos .= '
                    <table class="tg">
                        <tr>    
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Nombre: </strong> '.$data[$i]['tipoCirugia'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Dirección: </strong>'.$data[$i]['hospital'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Teléfono: </strong>'.$data[$i]['fechaCirugia'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>';
            } elseif ($key == 'nombreOtrosMeds') {  //Here you have to make a change according what data you want to show
                $algunaCirugia .= '
                    <table class="tg">
                        <tr>    
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Nombre: </strong> '.$data[$i]['nombreOtrosMeds'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Dirección: </strong>'.$data[$i]['hospital'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Teléfono: </strong>'.$data[$i]['fechaCirugia'].'</td>
                        </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <td class="tg-yw4l"><strong>Fax: </strong>'.$data[$i]['Nohospital'].'</td>
                       </tr>
                    </table>';
            }
            $element++;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
echo $otrosMedicos.'<br /><br />';
echo $algunaCirugia.'<br /><br />';
```

The above should echo:

```
Nombre: Cirugia2
DirecciÃ³n: Hospital2
TelÃ©fono: 2015-10-15


Nombre:
DirecciÃ³n: hospital1
TelÃ©fono: 2015-10-07
Fax: hospital hospitalizacion1
```

---

---

**Old** answer before the comments.

I cannot understand why you use next function here and you complex things in such a way but if you add `next($var)`:

```
foreach($_POST as $var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
        next($var);
        //Rest remains the same
```

It will echo:

```
Tipo de cirugÃ­a: cirugia1  Hospital: 2015-10-07    Fecha de cirugÃ­a: hospitalizacion1
Tipo de cirugÃ­a: Cirugia2  Hospital: 2015-10-15    Fecha de cirugÃ­a: Hospitalizacion2
```

Also, note that next() http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php

> advances the internal array pointer one place forward before returning
>   the element value

I think that you have sort of misused of this particular function here.

Comment: Cause first i have to iterate trough the $_POST variable, in there i found the 2 arrays, wich i have to iterate once more, i use the next($var) in the second foreach, wich is the one that checks if the value of the $_POST its an array if it is, then it does the table, and the next help me as it says advances the internal array pointer one place forward to get the element value i need

Comment: I think that must be an easier way to do this. Which are the array elements you want to fetch for each type of cirugía?

Comment: if the $_POST variable its an array, then i want to get first the value in [tipoCirugia] put it in a table row, and then i now that the next 2 values after [tipoCirugia] are [hospital] and [fechaCirugia] and i want to put them in the next 2 table rows

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick your are now one of my favorite persons on earth!

Comment: Oh, that's nice! I' m glad i helped you!